# Simulate AR(1) process in R with specified nonzero mean and AR coefficient

Tags: r, time-series, arima, simulation, autoregressive

I need to simulate an AR(1) process with the following equation in R:

$$
X_{t} = 5 + 0.5X_{t-1}+Z_t
$$

Where $Z_t$ ~ White Noise(0,1) and $T=500$.

I know I should be using the `arima.sim` function from the `forecast` package with parameters `n = 500` and `ar = c(0.5)` but I do not know how to account for the $ \delta = 5$ or the fact that $Z_t$ is white noise with mean 0 and sd 1. I have been unable to find clear documentation on how to do this.

Comment: what is $\delta$?

Comment: I vote to leave this question open, as the solution isn't totally programming-related.

Comment: It would help if you explained what $T$ is and where the $\delta$ comes from as otherwise it is unclear, at least to me, what you are asking.

Comment: $T$ is essentially the number of samples, $\delta$ is another component of the AR(1) process as specified in the equation as 5.

Answer (score 9):

Notice that this is the same model as 
$$
X_t - 10 = .5(X_{t-1} - 10) + Z_t .
$$
$10$ is the mean, while $5$ was the intercept. This means we can add ten to the mean zero series.

In other words, if you define $Y_t = X_t - 10$, then 
$$
Y_t = .5 Y_{t-1} + Z_t
$$
and use `arima.sim` to simulate that. After you have $\{Y_t\}$, then add $10$ to each value.

Code would look like this:

```
yt <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=500)
xt <- yt + 10
```

Regarding the standard deviation issue, that is covered in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I will have to relook into the documentation as I couldn't find where to adjust the mean and standard deviation of the white noise.